# PHP REST API update json_encode return null

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api

when i clicked the 'edit' to edit the database information, after echo json_encode this return null value not the database information I want to.
This is RESTAIP.php

```
       case "GET":

    if (isset($requestData->id))    {

        //Return the customer object
        $sc = CustomerMapper::getCustomer($requestData->id);
        var_dump($sc);
        //Set the header
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        //Barf out the JSON version

        echo json_encode($sc->jsonSerialize());
     }
```

When I debug, the last line has the database information, however, when I call this one, this return null.

```
 if($_GET["action"] == "edit") {
    //Call the rest client with GET, encode the result into a typed Customer

    $jc = json_decode(RestClient::call("GET",array("id"=>$_GET["id"])));

    var_dump($jc);

}
```

the $jc return null. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your `var_dump($sc);` is breaking the output of your API (making it non-JSON). You need to remove it.

Comment: @Nick When I removed, the new error code appear.  Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in.

Comment: It looks like your `RestClient::call` method is already doing the JSON parse